# is there any other syntex for lazy loaded module because in local machine all routes are working fine but in production (ng build) error occurs

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, angular-router

I was working on Angular 7.x.x around with deployment and is going through an issue and can't find a solution. the problem is that the path at the deployment mode of lazy-loaded components can't be resolved what path should I refer?

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },

  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },

      {
        path: 'setup',
        loadChildren: './modules/setup/setup.module#CorrSetupModule',
        data: { preload: true }
      },

    ]
  }
];
```

I expect all lazy loaded routes will work but they produce error

> core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Cannot find module
>   'app/modules/setup/setup.module'
>       at $_lazy_route_resource lazy namespace object:38
>       at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke
>   (zone.js:391)
>       at Object.onInvoke (core.js:17299)

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternate syntax from Angular `8.x.x` for the load children:

```
path: 'setup',
loadChildren: async () => import('./modules/setup/setup.module').then(module => module.CorrSetupModule)
data: { preload: true }
```

I faced a similar problem with lazy loaded modules on prod builds but it was related to the names that were created for the shared chunks.

I had success with changing the `namedChunks` option in `angular.json` to false:

```
"configurations": {
  "production": {
    //...
    "namedChunks": false, // setting this to false solved my problem
    "aot": true,
    //...
  }
}
```

Comment: #C_Ogoo I'm working on angular 7.x.x and this syntax  give me error..

"ERROR in Cannot read property 'loadChildren' of undefined"

Comment: yes, this wouldnt work in `Angular 7.x`. Did you try the namedChunks setting to false

Comment: Yes Sir,  also I found one new thing, when ts converts into js,  this statement  "./modules/setup/setup.module#CorrSetupModule"  terminated before # thats why #CorrSetupModule not found. is there another syntax in Angular 7.x.x for this?

Comment: path: 'setup',
loadChildren: async () => import('./modules/setup/setup.module').then(module => module.CorrSetupModule)
data: { preload: true } 

ERROR:

core.js:15724 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://ct16:8080/frontend/modules/setup/setup.module
TypeError: Failed to fetch dynamically imported module: http://ct16:8080/frontend/modules/setup/setup.module